# vlc android - Error with lib project

Tags: android, vlc

When I import the draft VLC source code and my attempt to instantiate activity that plays the video, I get an error NoClassDefFoundError, someone could help me

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you declare the activity in your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Indeed this in my manifest, I have not yet found any reason for this failure

Answer (score 0):

You mention "lib project" in the title of your question. Make sure the imported VLC project is marked as a lib project and not linked as a project dependency in the Java build path. The error message suggests that you may have accidentally mixed up the two project types.

Now, you don't mention which IDE you're using, but this is how you do it in Eclipse:

1. Remove the Java build path reference (right-click on the client project -> Properties -> Build path -> Projects and remove the VLC project).
2. Mark the VLC as a lib project (right-click the imported VLC project -> Properties -> Android and mark the "Is library" checkbox in the right pane).
3. Add the library project dependency to your client project (right-click your client project -> Properties -> Android and add the VLC library project in the right pane).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, use eclipse as my development environment .. I downloaded the VLC project from git, with its three main components, followed your instructions, but in step 3 lost all my project .. The R file, and between other things .. Try to import the. jar VLC but still with the same result .. could you please help me, I just need to play a streamming using this library as the VideoView is very slow.